# Accessing a closure variable when the method has an argument with the same name

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function() {
  var a = "Hello World";

  function foo(a) {
    alert(a);
  }
}
```

This will print the value passed to `foo`.

How can I access the `a` variable defined in the closure so that "Hello World" will be printed?

Comment: That's not valid, you can't have an anonymous function unless it's self executing.

Comment: What you have done has a proper name, is called [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Even when is made on purpose, as others pointed to you, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because it gets overridden in the functions scope. I also don't understand why such a construct would be useful. It's very confusing to say the least. **Just change the argument or variable name.**

Comment: Sure. That's of course what I did. I was just wondering whether it was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `var` when declaring a variable, it will be global and you can access it via `window.a`. This also work if the outer function is bound to the window object.

By the way, if you have control over variable and parameter names, you better name them in a better and less confusing way